# Using search.in with all

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Follwing statement find all profiles that has Facebook or twitter and this works:

```
$filter=SocialAccounts/any(x: search.in(x, 'Facebook,Twitter'))
```

But I cant find any samples for finding all that has both Facebook and twitter. I tried:

```
$filter=SocialAccounts/all(x: search.in(x, 'Facebook,Twitter'))
```

But this is not valid query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Search does not support the type of ‘all’ filter that you’re looking for. Using search.in with ‘all’ would be equivalent to using OR, but Azure Search can only handle AND in the body of an ‘all’ lambda (which is equivalent to OR in the body of an ‘any’ lambda).

You might try a workaround like this:

```
$filter=tags/any(t: t eq 'Facebook') and tags/any(t: t eq 'Twitter')
```

However, this isn't actually equivalent to using `all` with `search.in`. The query as expressed using `all` is matching documents where every social account is strictly either Facebook or Twitter. If any other social account is present, the document won’t match. The workaround doesn’t have this property. A document must have *at least* Facebook and Twitter in order to match, but not exclusively those. This is certainly a valid scenario; it just isn't the same as using `all` with `search.in`, which was the original question.

No matter how you try to rewrite the query, you won’t be able to express an equivalent to the `all` query. This is a limitation due to the way Azure Search stores collections of strings and other primitive types in the inverted index.

Please vote on user voice to help prioritize:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/37166749-efficient-way-to-express-a-true-all

A possible workaround is to use the new Complex Types feature, which does allow more expressive filters inside lambda expressions. For example, if you model tags as objects with a single `value` property instead of as a collection of strings, you should be able to execute a filter like this:

```
$filter=tags/all(t: search.in(t/value, 'Facebook,Twitter'))
```

In the REST API, you'd define `tags` like this:

```
{
  "name": "myindex",
  "fields": [
    ...
    {
      "name": "tags",
      "type": "Collection(Edm.ComplexType)",
      "fields": [
        { "name": "value", "type": "Edm.String", "filterable": true }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that this feature is in preview at the time of this writing, but will be generally available (and publicly documented) soon.

Comment: Your proposed workaround is actually incorrect. There is no way to achieve the equivalent of ‘all’ in this scenario. See my response on User Voice for details. I’ll post an answer based on this.

Comment: I will reach out for you internally Bruce.

Comment: Thomas, can you please mark this answer as accepted? That way I close duplicates and point them here.

Comment: Done, Thanks Bruce.